# Can I control my transformation into a werewolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I see no harm in continuing the quest line if it won't cause any problems and I can control it. However, I'll be going through the line much quicker if I have no control over the transformation.

When you contract Lycanthropy, are you able to control it naturally? Like, will I turn into a wolf when I walk outside and it's night time? Do moon phases have any effect on it?

Answer (score 20):

Normally, you'll be able to use your Beast Form power whenever you want, once per day. This power lasts for 2 ½ minutes, but can be extended by feeding on dead things.

However, there is a quest that will affect your ability to control your power:

> During *Ill Met By Moonlight*, you'll receive the *Ring of Hircine*. This cursed ring, once worn, can't be taken off and has a 10% chance every minute to cause you to transform against your will. Once the quest is complete, you'll get a non-cursed form (or lose the ring, depending on your choices).

Comment: once the ring is un-cursed, you gain free will of when the transformations take effect, giving you unlimited use of the werewolf transformation.

Answer (score 5):

You will be able voluntarily to turn into a werewolf once per day (This [ring](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ring_of_Hircine) that lets you do it multiple times). Once in werewolf form, you will have to feed on corpses to stay in werewolf form.

Comment: And to clarify, using the transformation is strictly voluntary

Comment: Thanks. I mostly just wanted to know if it was an involuntary transformation or not. This information makes it less of a problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Elder Scrolls Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Werewolf)

- Beast Form: (Skyrim) The Werewolf can transform into beast form for
  up to 2.5 minutes, which increases by 30 seconds if the werewolf
  feeds. Note- you may only feed upon the corpses of playable races.
  Falmer, for example, are inedible. Use caution when using the Beast
  Form in certain dungeons.
- Scent of Blood: (Skyrim 1st Totem) Detect life in a large area for 1 minute.
- Howl of the Pack:(Skyrim 2nd Totem) summon Two Wolves to fight at your side.
- Howl of Rage: (Skyrim 3rd Totem (default)) Causes nearby enemies up to level 25 to flee for 30 seconds.
- The three totems above have to be unlocked and then you can pray at them in the undercroft in Whiterun, you can use one at a time
  to as werewolf power.

Weaknesses

- No bonus from being well rested (Skyrim).

Answer (score 0):

I know how to be, and stay, a werewolf for as long as you want. All you have to do is hit the <kbd>~</kbd> key to bring up the console, then type `tgm` followed by `player.setrace werewolfbeastrace`, then you'll stay and be a werewolf. The guards wont attack you. I don't how to turn back so I'll have to look into that.

Comment: `tgm` toggles god mode, which is not needed. And to make sure you don't accidentally turn an NPC you clicked on in the console into a werewolf, you should use `player.setrace` instead of `setrace` alone. [Here's the uesp entry](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#player.setrace), you just have to read through `help race 0` in order to figure out your original race's name. But changing the race entirely is different from "not unwantedly becoming a werewolf", which the question actually asked though...

Comment: @Zommuter on higher levels TGM is the only way to survive combat as a werewolf, that hide doesn't protect against swords as well as dragonscale.

Comment: @kotekzot That may be then... Although in that case I prefer `TCAI` (toggle _combat_ AI) to simply be left alone