# Transforming into a werewolf

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been through the transformation into a werewolf with the companions but know do i just equip the power or do i have to press a key because i've equiped the power and i'm not turning into one.

Comment: and if you use the power (like any other spell)?

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37034/can-i-control-my-transformation-into-a-werewolf

Answer (score 3):

To equip it, you need to go 
Character Menu > Magic > Greater Powers > Werewolf power and select it. (A little white arrow should appear next to it on the left). This will equip the power.

To use the power, it's the same button to use shouts.

2 Werewolf notes:

- Only able to use once per day (with one exception*)
- When the power ends, you will have nothing equipped.

*The exception is to do a deadric quest and get the Ring of Hircine, to allow more transformations per day.

Comment: Yes, don't forget to put your armour back on afterwards or you'll be wondering why your next few fights are so difficult!